# C# - replace specific char inside String?

Tags: c#, string

I just want to simply replace all "." inside my string to be ","

```
String myString = "9.821.000.000";
if(myString.Contains("."))
{
    //do something that replace all . into ,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` has a `Replace` method with both char and string overloads:

```
myString = myString.Replace('.',',');
```

Comment: my god, didn't think it was that easy

Answer (score 2):

No need of `Contains` method..Just do

```
 myString=myString.Replace('.',',');
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Handling number formats that way is more secure.

Edit because of eccelent suggestion (rely on perma links way to often).
The best example on this topic:

```
 "#"   Digit placeholder


Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

More information: The "#" Custom Specifier.


1234.5678 ("#####") -> 1235

0.45678 ("#.##", en-US) -> .46

0.45678 ("#.##", fr-FR) -> ,46
```

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, but you might consider expanding this answer to include some relevant info from the link.  What is microsoft changes the structure of the MSDN site and this link breaks?  Then your answer would have little value to a future users/

Answer (score 0):

A simle string.replace should do it:

```
string myString = "9.821.000.000";
myString = myString.replace('.', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable type, you cannot change the string, you create other new.

```
String myString = "9.821.000.000";
if(myString.Contains("."))
{
    //do something that replace all . into ,
    myString = myString.Replace(".", ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should with [`Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method;

```
myString = myString.Replace('.',',');
```